# Trouble understanding why I get Segmentation fault (core dumped) in my code

Tags: c

This seems to be a relatively common question, but other posts aren't pointing me in the right direction on what to do.  I have a hard time seeing how this code doesn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){

double x,y,z;
double t = (x*x + y*y + z*z);
double s = sqrt(t);

printf("Component x:  ");
scanf("%f, x");

printf("Component y:  ");
scanf("%f, y");

printf("Component z:  ");
scanf("%f, z");

printf("Magnitude:  %f, s");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `double x,y,z;` have *undefined* values. So what happens next, is also undefined.

Comment: Uninitialized variables cause undefined behavior. Don't use variables without initializing them first. This is basic. Re-read your lessons on variables and initialization.

Comment: Undefined behavior for not passing a corresponding argument for a `"%"` conversion in `scanf()`.

Comment: The variables `t` and `s` are not being given a rule for *future* behaviour: they are (attempted to be) evaluated immediately. So you need to move those two lines down, past where you enter the data - which as EOF noticed, is where the segfault is caused.

Comment: `scanf("%f, x");`  -->  `scanf("%lf", &x);`   modern compilers will warn about this

Comment: @KenWhite Oh duh, that was stupid of me to miss that they weren't initialized.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @M.M Yeah, as KenWhite and other pointed out above, I declared but didn't initialize any of the values that I had.  When they pointed that out I fixed that error.  But thanks for writing it out, I would have initially written out ("%f", &x); instead of ("%lf", &x);  so thanks for that.  Saved me a headache down the line.

Comment: You also had the quote mark in the wrong place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are segfaulting because of the scanf's have both the type and variable in double quotes so there is nothing to read into. Additionally the "%f" should be changed to "%lf" for double.

```
scanf("%f, x");
```

This should have been

```
scanf("%lf", &x);
```

Also move the t and s computational statements after you have read value for z.

```
..
printf("Component z:  ");
scanf("%lf", &z);

double t = (x*x + y*y + z*z);
double s = sqrt(t);

printf("Magnitude:  %lf" , s);
..
```